# Test execution gets stopped after an assertion error in pytest

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

For the data driven testing, if there are 10 data sets, and the assertion fails for 3rd data set, then the rest of the 7 data sets are not considered for execution and the program gets stopped at that point completely.  I have tried by removeing the "raise e" line and that time all the data sets are considered for execution but at the end, the status is showing as PASSED which is absolutely not correct as I need to report failure for 3rd data set. Please let me know if you have any solutions for the same.

I have tried the following 2 methods, and it did not work. For the first one, test case executed 10 times for 10 datasets but even after a failure for the 3rd dataset, the test execution status is showing as PASSED which is not correct as the test case should be failed in the report.

For the second one, the test execution gets stopped completely after assertion failure in the 3rd dataset and the remaining data sets are not considered for execution.

My goal is to execute the test case for all data sets at once and then check the report for any failure.

```
        try:
            assert len(json_response_plan) == 1
        except Exception:
            pytest.raises(Exception)


        try:
            assert len(json_response_plan) == 1
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am new to Pytest and Python. Could you please provide solution in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

`pytest` will stop execution on the first failure **for a given test function**. Meaning, if you have 10 cases, but pass them to a single test function (in a for loop, for eg), it will stop on the first failure (i.e., jump to the next test function, or exit if there are no more test functions).
To solve this, the standard way is to make sure that each of those 10 cases be considered as separate test cases. This is where [parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) come into picture.

Consider this example:

```py
def my_dataset():
    return range(5)  # return your datasets from here

@pytest.fixture(params=my_dataset())
def my_fixture(request):
    yield request.param  # this will `yield` each of the datasets individually, thereby, considering it as individual tests

def test_me(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture < 4
```

`$ pytest tests/test_me.py -vvv`

```
tests/test_me.py::test_me[0] PASSED                                [ 20%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[1] PASSED                                [ 40%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[2] PASSED                                [ 60%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[3] PASSED                                [ 80%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[4] FAILED                                [100%]

================================ FAILURES ================================
_______________________________ test_me[4] _______________________________

my_fixture = 4

    def test_me(my_fixture):
>       assert my_fixture < 4
E       assert 4 < 4

tests/test_me.py:14: AssertionError
======================== short test summary info =========================
FAILED tests/test_me.py::test_me[4] - assert 4 < 4
====================== 1 failed, 4 passed in 0.19s =======================
```